# When trying to deploy to aws-lambda Error: operation not permitted occurs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy a function to aws that takes screenshot of the given url and tweets it.I am using puppeteer-core, @serverless-chrome/lambda and serverless-plugin-chrome to take screenshot following these articles(but instead of uploading to aws I tweet the image): https://swizec.com/blog/serverless-chrome-on-aws-lambda-the-guide-works-in-2019-beyond/swizec/9024 and https://nadeesha.github.io/headless-chrome-puppeteer-lambda-servelerless/.

It works fine on invoking locally and does everything but when I try to deploy it show an error that 'operation not permitted'. Below is the console log when I try to deploy.

```
Serverless: Injecting Headless Chrome...

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\xx\yy\zz\node_modules' -> 'C:\Users\xx\yy\zz\.build\node_modules'

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     OS:                     win32
     Node Version:           8.10.0
     Serverless Version:     1.45.1
```

I initially tried using just puppeteer but the package size was too big so I decided to go with this serverless-chrome approach and here is a relevant link but I haven't been able to solve it https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/issues/155

Answer (score 3):

Try removing your `.build` folder, before deploying.

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.   From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24076017).